# Symfony 4.3 forcing 'prod' on dev environment

Tags: symfony

I have an app built on Symfony 4.3.
It works as expected on local machine, and it's loading `.env.local` configuration file.
It also works as expected on production server, and it's loading `.env` file there.

But there is something wrong on development server.

### Development server settings

We set environment variable `APP_ENV` to value `dev`.
Bellow is output of `php bin/console about` on development environment:

```
-------------------- ---------------------------------
  Kernel
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  Type                 App\Kernel
  Environment          dev
  Debug                true
  Charset              UTF-8
  Cache directory      ./var/cache/dev (1.3 MiB)
  Log directory        ./var/log (138 KiB)
```

If I use `phpinfo()` function at the beginning of the  `/public/index.php` file, there is only 1 occurence of APP_ENV - and it is located under **Environment** section.

But if I use `phpinfo()` after loading `config/bootstrap.php`, few more occurences appears in **PHP Variables** section and they all contains `prod`:

```
$_SERVER['APP_ENV'] prod
$_ENV['APP_ENV']    prod
```

^ these 2 values were not there at the beginning of the  `/public/index.php` file, so it looks like Symfony is adding them and setting them to the wrong `prod` value.

**`.env.dev` file contains this:**

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
```

but It looks like this file isn't loaded at all and the `.env` is loaded instead of it.

I did some debugging and it looks like the wrong env file is loaded (and the additional variables shown in phpinfo() added) on this line in the `config/bootstrap.php` file:

```
// load all the .env files
(new Dotenv(false))->loadEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

Am I missing something? I thought that symfony environment is controlled by the `APP_ENV` environment variable only. But it looks like I'm wrong?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify things - **with development I mean remote development server** (it should be maybe called staging instead), not the localhost one.

Comment: *"It also works as expected on production server, and it's loading .env file there"* you shouldn't use `.env` file on production

Comment: @Cid I'm sorry, but I don't understand why. I thought the .env file contains some configurations used by the app (like DATABASE_URL, MAILER_URL). It is also stated in the .env file itself: ".env - contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app". But I'm still learning, so I will read more on this.

Comment: for local development, you can override values in `.env` via `.env.local` in current versions of symfony. see also: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-2-define-env-vars-per-environment

Comment: ignore my comment, this was the case for the applications created before [november 2018](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/configuration/dot-env-changes.html) when using `.env` could cause security issues on production

Comment: @jakumi thanks, I'm already using `.env.local` on localhost. But my problem is related to the development environment on development server.

Comment: server-set parameters (server passing stuff to fpm or similar) override .env stuff, afaik

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the parameters passed by (eg) webserver should be then shown in phpinfo() at the beginning of the input `public/index.php`. But they are not there, they are set after calling the `bootstrap.php`, so It looks like the Symfony is on the blame.